# Probability, expected values

Tags: probability

I do not know how to start the problem

In a bag there are n cards numbered from 1 to n. The cards are extracted successively with reposition.

(a) What is the expected value of extractions until the first number is repeated?

(b) What is the expected value of extractions until the first repetition occurs?

Can someone give me just an idea about how to solve it? thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I don't understand the difference between (a) and (b). Apparently you mean different things by "the first number is repeated" and "the first repetition occurs"?

Comment: In (a) you are looking at draws until the first card drawn is repeated.  In (b) you are looking at draws until you get a repeat of any card that has been drawn earlier (the first, second, third...)

Comment: @joriki In part a) I think it means that the first card drawn is repeated, while in part b) it means that some card is repeated.  In part a) the number of draws until success is unlimited, while in part b) there can't be more than $n$.

Comment: (b) is the mean rather than median version of the birthday problem and is $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \,n^k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know how to start the problem
>
> In a bag there are n cards numbered from 1 to n. The cards are extracted successively with reposition.
>
> (a) What is the expected value of extractions until the first number is repeated?

The very *first* extraction determines the value of the card; on each of the *subsequent* extractions the probability of a repeat is $1/n$.

Start by identifying the well know distribution to which belongs the count of those *subsequent* extractions, until the first repeat.

> (b) What is the expected value of extractions until the first repetition occurs?

Trickier.  Each subsequent extraction is either (I) a repeat or (II) a new card.

Start by using Indicator Random Variables; take $Y_i$ as the indication that no repeats have occurred before the $i$-th draw.  Then use linearity of expectation.